# Code w/o try block will throw exception. But with block, it won't

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have written a [userscript](https://gist.github.com/1524256/3562cbf8b629b6d46c9c70e20c4f4544bc4447c6), and run it in Greasemonkey 0.9.13.

If I remove the only `try... catch` block (line 54-66) but keep the code inside it, it will throw exceptions like below:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Operation is not supported"  code:
>   "9" nsresult: "0x80530009 (NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR)"  location:
>   "resource://greasemonkey/runScript.js Line: 29"]

However, stripped scripts run well in Chrome w/o any problems.

However, it will **NOT** print anything into console, which means codes in try block don't throw exception if wrapped by try block.

Can you guys tell me why it works?

This is the code snippet from that [linked source](https://gist.github.com/1524256/3562cbf8b629b6d46c9c70e20c4f4544bc4447c6):

```
var streamItems = $('div.main-content div.stream-item');
var streamItemsLength = streamItems.length;
var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
var scrollY = window.scrollY;
var y = scrollY + innerHeight;
var tweet;
var tweetHeight = 0;
try {
  for (var sumHeight = getHeaderHeight(), num = 0; sumHeight < y; num++, sumHeight += tweetHeight) {
    tweet = streamItems[num];
    tweetHeight = getHeight(tweet);
    if (tweetHeight == 0) {
      removeClass(tweet, 'hidden-tweet');
      tweetHeight = getHeight(tweet);
    }
  }
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e.stack);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script needs the `try` block (as you can see) because the logic of the `for` loop is very poor (it will often overrun the `streamItems` array and probably has a race condition when removing the `hidden-tweet` class).

You say it doesn't throw exceptions in Chrome, but it looks like this is just happenstance.  With the right conditions, it should fail in Chrome too -- or maybe Chrome's node manipulation is just enough different.  It doesn't matter, the code is poor.

As for it not printing anything to the console, are you sure?  It does in my tests.

But sometimes between anonymous function wrappers and event listeners, maybe the error `stack` might appear to be empty.

Comment: OK, i fix the end condition of `for` loop, and the problem seems to be fixed. And i dig into it, and find `div.stream-loading` element may be the cause. However, i'm not quite understand why it works on Chrome? Since i ignore the height of `div.stream-loading`, it may also break the script in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome might report the changed height immediately as the code seems to expect, but there may be a small delay in FF.  This is a major pain to test on twitter (a sight with a lot of FUBAR JS), so I'm making an educated guess here.

Comment: That may be the cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We use try/catch to catch any errors happened in code which is in try block. Based on your requirement you can decide whether you want to suppress the message (or) alert the user by adding some code in catch block. You can add some alert and see the message for your debugging purpose.

Based on exception message, it seems you are performing an operation (method/function call) on DOM object which is not supported, you need to revisit the code and see the function calls you are doing are supported.